# Why am I Getting error on panel's content script of Firefox Addon SDK?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

**Getting the following error, even after making the script empty I go this error.**

```
console.error: my-addon:
  Message: SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script
```

**Panel code of my addon:**

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");

var button = ToggleButton({
    id: "my-addon",
    label: "My Addon",
    icon: {
        "16": "./img/16-16.png",
        "32": "./img/32-32.png",
        "64": "./img/64-64.png"
    },
    onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = panels.Panel({
    contentURL: self.data.url("popup.html"),
    contentScript: self.data.url("js/pop_listener.js"),
    onHide: handleHide,
    width: 300,
    height: 550
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use  `contentScriptFile` instead of `contentScript`

Comment: I type in the error message into Google, follow the first result, and get exactly the right solution in five beautiful words. Amazing.